# Got crash after adding Onmarkerclicklistener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, onclicklistener

Like title, my app crash if I add OnMarkerClickListener or OnInfoWindowClickListener. Please help me. I have updated the code
This is my code, sorry I'm newbie :|

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
        btnBeHost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBeHost);
        requestQueue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //be a host btn when clicked
        ...

        //Welcome
        ...

        //get coordinates of motels and show on map
        //latitude request
        ...
        //longitude request
        ...
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
        queue.add(latReq);
        queue.add(lngReq);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"zzzz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        //set my location enabled
```

...
        }

Comment: Nobody could help you without shared logcat message

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide any code.

Comment: Can you expand the details of your question? Maybe show the code where you are having the issue, and any error messages.

Comment: Sorry mister, I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a method of mMap in your onCreate(), but mMap will be null until you assign it in onMapReady().

You will have to wait until *after* you assign it (perhaps later in onMap ready or in something you run subsequently) to call methods such as those which set up event listeners.

Comment: I placed it in onMapReady and worked perfectly. Thank you so much :>